# Can't insert html with <object> tag

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I'm struggling with ckeditor 4.5, as I'm creating plugins to insert specific tags in current document after having uploaded a file on my server.

For some specific file types, I want to embed the element. I can add `<audio>` or `<video>` tags (by using `allowContent=true` in my config file), but when I insert an `<object>` tag (to embed a pdf file), the tag is just ignored.

I already tested adding `config.extraAllowedContent = 'object[id, name, width, height, data, type]` to the config file, with no avail.

I found some workarounds by adding a `<div>` around the `<object>`, but the pdf viewer is not displayed in the editor (but the `<object>` tag is there).

I think I'm doing something wrong with ACF, but I really don't see what.

Comment: FYI, I also tried using the 'unfiltered_html' mode in the insertHtml method, with no more success

Answer (score 0):

only wrapped the  tag with

or , and if you use wordpress  , or drupal try to disable Advanced content filter from cms

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`<object>` is not recommended for PDF and should not be a part of an editable area. There is no way it can be editable like text or paragraph. However, it can be a non-editable element inside the editor, with some editable parts. This is what CKEditor call widget, here is a tutorial how to create it: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/widget_sdk_intro.html

Note PDF format is not normally classed as "Media" more generally "Document" but there are two ways to embed. One is to use the allMedia plugin that does include PDF as a *media* format ;-) the other is to include content via google docs. So review the various "Demonstrations" on the website.

[image]